# Avoiding quotes in a map variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I'm trying to create a query with variables from a map function, but the content stored in one of these fields does contain `'` (quotes, like Barney's). So everytime it cracks since the `'` will break the statement. How can I get around it? 
I tried to use the `.split` function but no sucess.
No worries about SQL Injection since I'm just loading data from an API to my db.

Code:

```
query_values = activities.map do |activity|
  '(' +
  "#{activity['id']},
  ""'#{activity['type']}""'" #using ""' just to fill the column when empty cells are raised
  +')'

end
query = "INSERT INTO pd_activities  VALUES #{query_values.join(', ')}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blindly inserting stuff is simply insane. **Don't do it** even if you think your data is okay. When you *assume* you get into trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to do this properly is listed on the [cheat sheet](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html):

```
db[:pd_activities].insert(
  id: activity['id'],
  type: activity['type']
)
```

This takes care of all the escaping issues for you. If all `activity` has is those two keys you might even be able to do this:

```
db[:pd_activities].insert(activity)
```

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, please raise your glasses in a toast to tadman, who just hit the century mark!

Comment: This put it over the top. Thanks!